# JavaMail ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email from a Java Application but whenever I run the code found online [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api)

When I run the code I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at nameInProgress.Driver.main(Driver.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is relating to how I have attached the source (I am not using maven), I have viewed some other solutions on here, the highest suggests attaching a source code zip, but the link to that file is no longer valid and I cannot find it on my own.

EDIT: I have created a build path to JavaMail but I am still receiving this error.

Comment: Did you add JavaMail jar files to classpath / buildpah / whatever your IDE calls it?

Comment: Does your application compile in eclipse? If so you should add the same jars on your project build path to your web-inf/lib folder.  Do you have a mail server setup on your machine at localhost? use that or you could try to use google or something...or you could install your own mail server and configure on your machine

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you don't have the javax mail jar/dependency. If you aren't using a dependency manager then you'll need to get the jar and add it to your classpath. I found a link for the jar [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Apologies for being unclear, I have already tried downloading that exact java file and connected it to my program using the build path feature, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: @j.McNair - There are three separate types of files which you are confusing.  A .java file contains the source code (human readable) of a java class.  A .class file contains the byte code (not intended to be human readable) of a java class (the "javac" program converts a .java file to a .class file).  Finally, a .jar file contains a set of .class files.  When you want your code (written in your .java file) to use some external library, you need to provide that library as either a .class or .jar to both "javac" and "java", via the CLASSPATH.  Putting the library's .java there will not work.